# UIActionSheet's separate lines overlap with other lines

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiactionsheet

I'm adding UIActionSheet with 100 sheets to UIView.

Here is a code.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Choose Number"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                              destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
}

actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
cancelIndex = actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex;
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXy2r.png)

The line between 22 and 23 overlaps.

What is problem?

Comment: Use a `UIPickerView` to get a number like this from the user. A `UIActionSheet` is not appropriate at all.

Comment: Thx. I see. I changed UIActionSheet to UIPickerView!